# Confused about how to store extracted sub-string features before running machine learning

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, machine-learning, feature-extraction, data-manipulation

I have some data with name and ethnicity

```
j-bte letourneau   scotish
jane mc-earthar    french   
amabil bonneau   english
```

I then normalize the name as such by replacing the space with "#" and add trailing "?" to standardize the total length of the name entries. I would like to use sequential three-letter substring as my feature to predict ethnicity.

```
                                name_filled      substr1 substr2 substr3  \
0   j-bte#letourneau???????????????????????????     j-b     -bt     bte   
1   jane#mc-earthar????????????????????????????     jan     ane     ne#   
2   amabil#bonneau?????????????????????????????     ama     mab     abi
```

Here is my code for data manipulation to this point:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import re

# Get csv file into data frame
data = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\KubiK\Desktop\OddNames_sampleData.csv")
frame = DataFrame(data)
frame.columns = ["name", "ethnicity"]
name = frame.name
ethnicity = frame.ethnicity

# Remove missing ethnicity data cases
index_missEthnic = frame.ethnicity.isnull()
index_missName = frame.name.isnull()
frame2 = frame.loc[~index_missEthnic, :]
frame3 = frame2.loc[~index_missName, :]

# Make all letters into lowercase
frame3.loc[:, "name"] = frame3["name"].str.lower()
frame3.loc[:, "ethnicity"] = frame3["ethnicity"].str.lower()

# Remove all non-alphabetical characters in Name
frame3.loc[:, "name"] = frame3["name"].str.replace(r'[^a-zA-Z\s\-]', '') # Retain space and hyphen

# Replace empty space as "#"
frame3.loc[:, "name"] = frame3["name"].str.replace('[\s]', '#')

# Find the longest name in the dataset
##frame3["name_length"] = frame3["name"].str.len()
##nameLength = frame3.name_length
##print nameLength.max() # Longest name has !!!40 characters!!! including spaces and hyphens

# Add "?" to fill spaces up to 43 characters
frame3["name_filled"] = frame3["name"].str.pad(side="right", width=43, fillchar="?")

# Split into three-character strings
for i in range(1, 41):
    substr = "substr" + str(i)
    frame3[substr] = frame3["name_filled"].str[i-1:i+2]
```

My question is, would it be a problem to store my 3-character substring this way to run the machine learning algorithm? This could be a problem as the example below.

Imagine two Chinese people both with the last name Chan, but one is called "Li Chan" and the other is called "Joseph Chan".

The Chan will be split into "cha" and "han", but for the first case, the "cha" will be stored in the str4 while the other will be stored in the str8 because the first name pushes it to be stored much later. I wonder if I could and should store the 3-character substrings into just one single variable as a list (for example: ["j-b", "-bt", "bte"] for substr variable for case 0), and if the substrings are stored into one single variable, can it be run with machine learning algorithms to predict ethnicity?

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to split the name to forenames and surnames and then perform the 3 character splitting?

Comment: Yes it would, and I am thinking of doing it too (not hard at all), but the issue is I will be running into the same challenge of how to store them? Whether in one single variable as a list, or in separate variables.

Comment: Personally I'd store it as separate variables but you'd then have to determine the max num of columns, a list would be ok but you then have to iterate over the list or convert into an appropriate datatype for training your model on